# How do I pass data from html form to node.js file stored on Google Cloud?

Tags: html, node.js, google-cloud-platform

Trying to pass some data from an HTML form to a node.js function in Google Cloud Platform. I've tried using AJAX, but I didn't have any luck with that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This article might help you. https://itnext.io/how-to-handle-the-post-request-body-in-node-js-without-using-a-framework-cd2038b93190

Comment: you provide more information?.

Things i could thing are:

1. You haven't exposed your GCP service
2. You don't have well configured your node app
3. Maybe you need to parse the data (bodyparser dependencie)

Answer (score 0):

Many apps need to do background processing outside of the context of a web request. The tutorial [1] creates a web app that lets users input text to translate, and then displays a list of previous translations. The translation is done in a background process to avoid blocking the user's request.

Please have the link [1] to know details how it works.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/background-processing